# Differences among "wahr", "echt", "wirklich", "tatsächlich", "eigentlich"?

Tags: difference

What are the differences between *wahr*, *echt*, *wirklich*, *tatsächlich* and *eigentlich*?
They all seem to mean "real/really, actual/actually"...

Dictionaries didn't help.

Comment: This question is far too broad. In particular, _eigentlich_ isn't similar at all to the other words. If the dictionaries you consulted can't make the differences clear, you should try a better dictionary.

Comment: Doesn't eigentlich mean "real, actual" ?

Comment: Rather the opposite: _Ich bin eigentlich nicht da_ means that I **am** here (but perhaps shouldn't be).

Comment: This is tooooo broad. Sounds like you want to know 5(5-1)/2 comparisons.

Comment: All words indeed have some overlap—well, more or less. And though, they also have a clear distinct (predominant) meaning. If you had at least tell us why dictionaries didn't help, we could elaborate on the unclear part. But the question as it stands is off-topic for both being too broad and being general reference.

Comment: @chirlu, there is also the adjective *eigentlich*.

Comment: They all seem to mean "real/really, actual/actually"!

Comment: „wahr“ means true/in fact; „echt“ means not fake; „wirklich“ means real, in reality, actually; „tatsächlich“ means indeed; „eigentlich“ means actually.

Comment: But isn't true= "not fake"?
Sorry but I still don't get it, all those definitions look alike @@

Comment: No. “Water boils at 100 degrees celsius.” is a true statement. But it is not a *not fake* statement. I can say “This is not a fake iPhone although it comes from China.” but saying “This is a true iPhone...” changes the meaning, doesn’t it?

Comment: Sorry, too general. And forget looking for one-to-one translations of similar terms. See the "tree - wood - forest" namespace in different languages.

Comment: This would be tedious to answer, but that does not mean that it is not a valid question.

Comment: @idmean Um, so "wahr" means "fact, not imaginary" and "wirklich" means "not fake products"....right?
This is so frustrating, all these words seem to share the same word in English, which makes it difficult for me to differenciate@@